# Swashbuckle / Swagger missing enum information when enum is in path

Tags: c#, enums, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a C# .Net 6 API using Swashbuckle to generate Swagger docs for clients.

I have Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.3.1 and *.Filters 7.02 installed.

In Startup.cs, I have

```
...
    swaggerOptions.UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums();
    swaggerOptions.SchemaFilter<EnumDescriptionFilter>(); // Custom filter.
...

.AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    })
```

I have several enums in the APIs that are string serialized.  This works great when the enum is in the query string:
[image]

However, this doesn't work when the enum is in the path:
[image]

I've tried fiddling with the configuration, experimenting with the Annotations package, switching to Newtonsoft, etc. but have had no such luck.

If I change the type of the parameter to string then I get a type of string in the swagger, but I don't get the possible values.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks.

---

Update.  Upon further playing around, in the querystring only List show up correctly.  If I add `[FromQuery] VehicleType vehicleType` to a route, then it shows up without a type.

At the same time, `[FromQuery] List<VehicleType> vehicleTypes` shows up correctly.

---

Updated 2: Looks like this is an issue with OpenAPI.NET
[https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1329#:~:text=Enum%20type%20is%20missing%20%28look%20at%20JustEnum%20in,and%20serialization%20to%20JSON%20behavior%20from%20that%20library](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1329#:%7E:text=Enum%20type%20is%20missing%20%28look%20at%20JustEnum%20in,and%20serialization%20to%20JSON%20behavior%20from%20that%20library).

As per the thread, this is a work around for the bug:

```
swaggerGenOptions.UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums();
```